# Why is the Jyeshtha Nakshatra named so?

Tags: nakshatra, astrology

Jyeshtha in Sanskrit means 'the eldest'. Why is Jyeshtha called as the eldest Nakshatra in Jyotisha?

Comment: It is an interesting question. I up voted.  :p

Comment: @Surya I know right! :D

Comment: I don't think it require a new tag `jyeshta` here. btw, nice question.

Comment: The 27 constellations are the daughters of Daksha prajapati and were married to Chandra.

Comment: @SreeCharan Yup, someone said it might have to do with brightness of the star in the sky as Jyeshtha also means splendour. Although, I am yet to find any proper references.